# kapt Build Fails With Dagger Android Processor

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

I am attempting to include the Dagger Android Processor (documented [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html)) in my project with the [Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kapt-annotation-processing-for-kotlin/) (kapt).

I have included the proper dependencies in my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    })

    // Support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"

    // Google libraries
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.10"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.10"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.10"

    // ReactiveX libraries
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.9"

    // Kotlin libraries
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2"

    // Test instrumentation
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

But when I build the project I get the following `GradleException`:

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Internal compiler error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:9)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptTask.compile(KaptTask.kt:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
```

According to the Kotlin 1.0.4 [release changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/09/kotlin-1-0-4-is-here/):

> You should enable [`generateStubs`] only if you’ve run into problems with the
>   default `kapt` annotation processing implementation.

Which I tried, but no luck.

---

Root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you show your root build.gradle as well?

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann Sure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bah, I missed part of the error message that was before the break:

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: /Users/me/Downloads/App/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/app/ui/module/main/MainActivityModule.java:10: error: @dagger.android.ActivityKey methods should bind dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.app.Activity>, not dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? super android.app.Activity>. See google.github.io/dagger/android
e: 

e:     public abstract dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? super android.app.Activity> bindMainActivityInjectorFactory(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                                                                                          ^

w: warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]'
w: 


e: /Users/me/Downloads/App/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/app/ApplicationComponent.kt: (1, 1): Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please see the error messages above.
```

I was using the `in` variance annotation instead of the `out` annotation when creating the `AndroidInjector.Factory`.

```
@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(MainActivitySubcomponent::class))
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Binds @IntoMap @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindMainActivityInjectorFactory(
            builder: MainActivitySubcomponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity> // Was using `in` annotation instead of `out`
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution? I don't get it.

Comment: @Semanticer In Java wildcards can either be unbounded, [upper bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) or [lower bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) by using either no keyword, the `extends` keyword or the `super` keyword (respectively). These keywords correspond to the `in` and `out` variance annotations in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). The error states that I was using `extends` when I should be using `super`; or when translated to Kotlin, `in` when I should be using `out`.

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe You *want* to generate the same error logs? You should be able to just copy the `MainActivityModule` above, but using the `in` variance (`AndroidInjector.Factory<in Activity>`), and add it to your `AppComponent` (or any part of your Dagger object graph).

Comment: Don't you hope that `kapt` errors find their way into the standard Studio error log pane?  Boy, I sure do..

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is related to the **kotlin-stdlib-jre7**, it doesn't work properly with dagger, I suggest you change this  **kotlin-stdlib-jre7** for **kotlin-stdlib** :

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2"
```

instead of:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2"
```

it works for me.

Comment: This one fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same problem.
I had to take off from my build.gradle:

1. `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`
2. `kapt 'groupId:artifactId:$kapt_version'`

And I added this (straight away after apply plug:....):

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I hope this could help someone else.

Comment: You do not need `generateStubs = true` if you applied the `kotlin-kapt` plugin, it is for the older kapt. Gradle will show the warning about this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single reason for this build failure. It's not always related to **kotlin** as well.

Check your logs in **Android studio**'s **Gradle Console** 
for clear information about the cause.
You can find the clue about the failure.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways but the error message was not meaningful after next day I add

`MoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val movieService: MovieService): ViewModel()` then :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with kapt and I dissolved it to add:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to SDK manager in Android studio and install NDK. it works for me.